# Image from webbrowser control to picturebox - C#

Tags: c#, .net, browser, picturebox

I have picturebox and webbrowser control.
in webbrowser control I'm displaying page with image.
This image is visible. I can't pass to picture box url of this image because it will not display. This image is not visible if you enter it's page directy from address bar.

Is there any way to get that image from browser cache or any other way?

I want to get captcha image that appears on this page after viewing one add.

http://www.clix-cents.com/pages/clickads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the image by copying it to the clipboard. JavaScript can copy the img to clipboard.

```
mshtml.HTMLWindow2Class w2 = webBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow as mshtml.HTMLWindow2Class;
w2.execScript("var ctrlRange = document.body.createControlRange();ctrlRange.add(document.getElementById('img1'));ctrlRange.execCommand('Copy');", "javascript");
Image image2 = Clipboard.GetImage();
pictureBox1.Image = image2;
```

Comment: Hello. I'm getting this error: http://img863.imageshack.us/img863/3277/201103111529sitebot.jpg

Comment: Add reference to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll`

Comment: Apply the `Invoke` thing that you did with `GetDocumentText` to this `GetImageById` function.

Comment: Hello, what if the image has no imageid? `<img src="/captcha.php?imagehash=c58a1ed62426658464722336dc2330ed" class="captcha" alt="Visual Confirmation Security Code" title="Visual Confirmation Security Code">`??? thanks

Comment: @Smith In that case, you might want to search for the HtmlElement which has the TagName = "IMG" and ClassName = "captcha" and maybe even Alt = "Visual Confirmation Security Code". Then assign an ID to the HtmlElement and then use the same code to get the image. Alternatively, you could write some javascript to select that specific image using those parameters. If you want more information, please post a new question. It's very hard to edit in the comments box.